# Input type range array value and ids for submit

Tags: javascript, angularjs, input, ionic-framework, range

I'm try to get the array of range type values and ids to submit in ionic AngularJS

Here's my HTML:

```
<ion-view view-title="Survey">
 <ion-content class="padding survey">
  <h4 class="animated flash"><i class="fa fa-exclamation" aria-hidden="true">
   </i> {{surveys.displayTitle}}</h4>

<section class="item" ng-repeat="survey in surveys.questions">
  <p>{{survey.displayTitle}} <i class="fa fa-check" aria-hidden="true"></i></p>
  <div class="range">
    <i class="icon ion-sad"></i>
    <input type="range" min="{{min}}" max="{{max}}" name="" id="{{survey.id}}" ng-model='modelValue' value="{{modelValue}}">
    <i class="icon ion-happy"></i>
  </div>
</section>

<button class="button button-block button-assertive" ng-click="survey()">
  <span ng-hide="loading">Submit <i class="fa fa-paper-plane" aria-hidden="true"></i></span>
  <span ng-show="loading">Please wait <i class="fa fa-spinner fa-spin"></i></span>
</button>
```

And here is my controller button click

```
$scope.survey = function(){
   $scope.loading = true;
   $http.post(sharingDataService.getApiUrl() + '/app/surveylink', {
       "answers" : [
         {"questionId" : 1, "value" : $scope.value},
         {"questionId" : 2, "value" : $scope.value},
         {"questionId" : 3, "value" : $scope.value},
         {"questionId" : 4, "value" : $scope.value}
       ]
   }).then(function (data) {
       console.log(data);
   }
);
```

Comment: What's the question? I don't understand what you're trying to accomplish.

Comment: i need to get the values and ids form html to controller and submit it

Comment: Have a look at https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngModel

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can bind `range` with a `property`(named whatever, here `modelValue` for eaxmple) to `survey` with `ng-model`. This property will be updated when `range` has been changed.

And you can get the changed value in controller by :

```
"answers" : [
     {"questionId" : 1, "value" : $scope.surveys.questions[0].modelValue},
     {"questionId" : 2, "value" : $scope.surveys.questions[1].modelValue},
     {"questionId" : 3, "value" : $scope.surveys.questions[2].modelValue},
     {"questionId" : 4, "value" : $scope.surveys.questions[3].modelValue}
]
```

**UPD:**

If you bind `range` with  both `ng-model` and `value` (different values), the `value` property will be ignored.

```js
angular.module("app", [])
  .controller("myCtrl", function($scope) {
    $scope.min = 10;
    $scope.max = 100;
    $scope.modelValue = 50;
    $scope.surveys = {
      questions: [
        {
          id: 1,
          detail: 'question1',
          modelValue: 50
        },
        {
          id: 2,
          detail: 'question2',
          modelValue: 60
        },
      ]
    }
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.4/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="myCtrl">
  <section class="item" ng-repeat="survey in surveys.questions">
    <div class="range">
      <input type="range" min="{{min}}" max="{{max}}" name="" id="{{survey.id}}" ng-model='survey.modelValue' value="modelValue" >
      {{survey.modelValue}}
    </div>
  </section>
  {{surveys.questions}}
</div>
```

Comment: @eldewiny oops, I just found a typo I have made which should be `$scope.surveys.questions[3]`, check it again.

Comment: i update my code but i get in the console error : TypeError: Cannot read property 'modelValue' of undefined

Comment: @eldewiny have you ever changed each range's value? if not, this will heppen.   How about add the property while  `$scope.surveys` is initialized.

Comment: <input type="range" min="{{min}}" max="{{max}}" name="{{$index + 1}}" id="{{survey.id}}" ng-model='survey.modelValue' value="{{modelValue}}">

Comment: "answers" : [
        {"questionId" : 1, "value" : $scope.surveys.questions[0].modelValue},
        {"questionId" : 2, "value" : $scope.surveys.questions[1].modelValue},
        {"questionId" : 3, "value" : $scope.surveys.questions[3].modelValue},
        {"questionId" : 4, "value" : $scope.surveys.questions[4].modelValue}
      ]

Comment: @eldewiny angularjs version doesn't matter. I have update code snippet to latest version of angularjs

Comment: @eldewiny I have updated the sample based on my last comment.

Comment: i made almost copy and paste to your code but the console can't find modelValue ,

Comment: @eldewiny have you changed `$scope.surveys.questions[4]` to `$scope.surveys.questions[3]`?

Comment: i update it but i get 500 error say Message: "Undefined index: value" and here is my code

Comment: "answers" : [
                    {"questionId" : 1, "value" : $scope.surveys.questions[0].modelValue},
                    {"questionId" : 2, "value" : $scope.surveys.questions[1].modelValue},
                    {"questionId" : 3, "value" : $scope.surveys.questions[2].modelValue},
                    {"questionId" : 4, "value" : $scope.surveys.questions[3].modelValue}
                ]}

Comment: @eldewiny error 500 is a server error, this is not relevant to your current question, you can just confirm `$scope.surveys.questions[0] ~ $scope.surveys.questions[3]` have kept the ranges value with property `modelValue`

Comment: i'm really sorry, but i did't get what you main.

Comment: @eldewiny ok, please update your question with the details about the error.

Comment: 500 Internal Server Error  Message: "Undefined index: value"

Comment: HTML : <section class="item" ng-repeat="survey in surveys.questions">
      <p>{{survey.displayTitle}} <i class="fa fa-check" aria-hidden="true"></i></p>
      <div class="range">
        <i class="icon ion-sad"></i>
        <input type="range" min="{{min}}" max="{{max}}" name="" id="{{survey.id}}" ng-model='modelValue' ng-value="modelValue" value="{{modelValue}}" >
        <p>{{modelValue}}</p>
        <i class="icon ion-happy"></i>
      </div>
    </section>

Comment: @eldewiny see this is a server error. then look back to my previous comment.

Comment: $http.post(sharingDataService.getApiUrl() + '/app/survey/saveAnswers', {
                "answers" : [
                    {"questionId" : 1, "value" : $scope.surveys.questions[0].modelValue},
                    {"questionId" : 2, "value" : $scope.surveys.questions[1].modelValue},
                    {"questionId" : 3, "value" : $scope.surveys.questions[2].modelValue},
                    {"questionId" : 4, "value" : $scope.surveys.questions[3].modelValue}
                ]}
        ).then(function (data) {
            console.log(data);
        });

Comment: @eldewiny change `ng-model='modelValue'` to `ng-model="survey.modelValue"`

Comment: i add it but did't work and even the range value did't move to

Comment: @eldewiny sorry, I'm going out right now. Basically I have provided the working example and solution. you have to find out the differences beween it and your app. I'll be back tomorrow. Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

**Frist of all thanks pengyy for help
and here is the complate foreach angularjs way**

```
// your data object
var obj = $scope.surveys.questions;
        var answers = [];
        angular.forEach(obj, function(value, key) {
            answers.push({"questionId" : value.id, "value" : value.modelValue});
        });

        $http.post(sharingDataService.getApiUrl() + '/your link', {
                "answers" : answers}
        ).then(function (data) {
            your code
        });
```